# What is the best way to implement strong security standards for $_GET id's?

Tags: php, security

I am seeking the strongest security measure for people changing the IDs in the URL for comments, blogs, inbox etc...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Validating the data you get is a great idea, if you're expecting digit, make sure you get digits.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']) && ctype_digit($_GET['id']))
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}else
{
  $id = 0;
}
```

If your concern is people changing urls to see things, like requesting image 44 when you only wanted to show them image 42 you've got a few options:

- Include various checks on the page to ensure the user has the appropriate permission to use the item.
- Hash the item in the url to make items immutable.
- Don't use sequential numbers, use random numbers or hashes.

Comment: Thanks! Great advice...this is new to me though, so are you saying if I add the && ctype_digit($_GET['id']))
{
to the end of my if(issest) that should do it? or should I do that and the additional checks of the users? ifso, what is a good way to do that?

Comment: Adding the ctype_digit() check will ensure that the user has only entered digits.

The user can still change what is in the url (for example, changing a 44 to a 45). This check will not catch that kind of modification.

Answer (score 7):

Check the session permissions to see if they are allowed to perform the action?

If they're allowed to do it, then carry out the action. If not, then give them a 403.

Comment: +1 for the right answer. You can't put any information in your url that isn't completely visible to the enduser...The best you can do is try to obscure it. If you're security depends on other people not seeing through the obscurity, you've already failed. Authenticate the user, store that information, and use it to verify permissions.

Answer (score 3):

If it's just an ID (numeric, I guess), all you have to do is validate it as an integer:

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

Then you can query your database. You will get empty return sets when the ID does not exist and when it is invalid (because `$id` will be `0` in that case).

Comment: (int) casts the value to an integer, it doesn't validate it. If someone enters "23a312" you get 23.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. Bad wording, I guess.

Comment: Although that can still be taken as intended in my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine that digitally signing the get requests and appending that to the URL would work.

Sign it with a private key known only to your application, and then hash the GET variables and provide a signature in a &sig=blahblahblah.

That would probably work, but I don't really understand the need for protecting the GET variables.  If designed properly, it really shouldn't matter what the GET variables are.  A properly designed app shouldn't allow user GET variables to do anything damaging.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, do not rely on $_GET for critical information. Always double-check whether the user has permission to view that comment id, blog id, whatever. As for ID filtering - simple `intval()` will help (but don't forget to handle 0's also)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you find [phpsec.org guide to php security, chapter 2, form processing](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html) interesting.